# Why server are sending blank string to the client?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing program in java using sockets and threads. In my Client class I have method where Client can add services and send them to server. Server recieves data and store them into ArrayList. My problem is that after storing the service I want to send message back to the client, so he would know that service was succesfully added, but unfortunately what I'm recieving is a blank String.

Here's my code:

```
  //method from client class

  private static void addServices() throws IOException{
   input= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
   inputClient=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
   output= new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
   System.out.print("\nName of service: ");
   String name=input.readLine();
   output.println(name);
   output.flush();
   System.out.print("\nData of service: ");
   String data=input.readLine();
   output.println(data);
   output.flush();
   String getMsg;
   getMsg=inputClient.readLine(); //here I got blank string from server
   System.out.println(getMsg);
}


  //method from Server class

  private void addServices()throws IOException{
    reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    output=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    String name=reader.readLine();
    String data=reader.readLine();
    serviceList.add(new Service(login,name,true,data));
    String msg="\nService added succesfully.";
    output.println(msg); // here's message I wanna sent to the client
    output.flush();
  }
```

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong and why? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened:
A message `"\nService added succesfully."` was sent to the client. Then the `inputClient.readLine()` method reads a string between the 0th character and a line-termination character, which is an empty string before the `"\n"` in the message. Try removing the `\n` and it should get the message correctly.